# Open multiple applications sequentially via Window batch file

Tags: windows-7, batch

To test an SSD RAID setup I would like some way of scripting the sequantial launch of a number of programs.

How can I do this?

With a Windows batch file I can only either open all at once og wait for previous program to terminate.

EDIT: The main objective is to know when all the programs have finished loading.

Comment: Well, technically...it does open 'in order' and not all at once, it just does it very fast. ;)

Comment: Yeah, maybe what I want does not make sense. But the plan was for the next program to start launching when the previous had finished loading.

Comment: sequantial  --> sequential
once og wait --> once oR wait

Answer (score 1):

You say the following:

> With a Windows batch file I can only either open all at once og wait for previous program to terminate.

So you need to [make delay between the program launches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735285/how-to-wait-in-a-batch-script)?

Comment: The main purpose of my request was to make sure that if the last program in my list of programs to launch was Notepad, the when it all had finished the Notepad window would be the top most window.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Sikuli](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/) would work for you, a *"visual technology to search and automate graphical user interfaces (GUI) using images (screenshots)."* Use it to wait for the image of successfully started app#1, then launch app#2,...

Answer (score 0):

Using [StartX](http://www.naughter.com/startx.html) you can do what you ask. :-)

Comment: Low Quality alert

Comment: @soandos: Thanks, will improve when I am at home again.

Answer (score 0):

No need to install external tools, just use the [`start` command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

For instance:

```
start "" calc
start "" "%PROGRAMFILES%\MyCustomApp\App.exe"
start "" notepad "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\doc.txt"
```

You may want to add the `/B` switch to avoid the creation of another console window, but the launched apps `stdout` will mix in the launching console this way.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will solve your task, but if you write this way

```
cmd /C calc.exe
cmd /C calc.exe
```

in your batch file, then the shell will launch first calc, wait unitl you close it, then run the second.

hope it helps

Comment: No good. That means that i actively have to close the program.